# Sum value in periodic time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I want sum work time of machine that save in table but I need sum in periodic time 
for example between 2019.07.10 and 2018.04.05 every 7 days sum values.

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a recursive CTE that returns all the 7 days intervals between the specified days:

```
declare @mindate date = '2018-04-05';
declare @maxdate date = '2019-07-10';
with cte as (
  select 
    @mindate startdate, 
    dateadd(day, 6, @mindate) enddate 
  union all 
  select 
    dateadd(day, 1, enddate),  
    case 
      when dateadd(day, 6, enddate) > @maxdate then @maxdate
      else dateadd(day, 6, enddate)
    end  
  from cte 
  where cte.enddate < @maxdate
)
select c.startdate, c.enddate, sum(hours) totalhours 
from cte c left join tablename t
on t.date between c.startdate and c.enddate
group by c.startdate, c.enddate
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c5cdb158374abd1a6fd60e028174b9f1).
Results:

```
> startdate  | enddate    | totalhours
> :----------| :--------- | ---------:
> 05/04/2018 | 11/04/2018 |         14
> ....................................
> 16/08/2018 | 21/08/2018 |         11
> ....................................
> 28/08/2018 | 02/09/2018 |          1
> ....................................
```

Answer (score 1):

create procedure spCalculateWorkingHours
declare @DaysGap tinyint
as
begin
    declare @MinWorkingDate date
    declare @MaxWorkingDate date
    declare @weekStratDay date
    declare @WeekEndDay date

```
create table #temp
(WeekStartDay date,
 WeekEndDay date,
 WorkingHours int)

select @minWorkingdate = min(workingdate) from yourtable
select @MaxWorkingDate = Max(workingdate) from yourtable
set @daysGap=7
set @weekStratDay=@MinWorkingDate

while (@weekStratDay<@MaxWorkingDate)
    begin
        set @WeekEndDay dateadd(day,@DaysGap,@weekStratDay)

        insert into #temp
        select @minWorkingdate,@WeekEndDay,sum(hours) from yourtable where workingdate between @minWorkingdate and @WeekEndDay
        group by @minWorkingdate,@WeekEndDay

        set @weekStratDay=dateadd(day,1,@WeekEndDay)
    end

select * from #temp
```

end

Answer (score 0):

I would just subtract the smaller value and divide the difference by 7.  Something like this:

```
select min(datecol), sum(worktime)
from t
group by datediff(day, '2018-04-05', <datecol>) / 7
order by min(datecol);
```

If you have data on every day, this should be exactly what you need.